# Error occurres when get binary from broker DB by BinaryDistributionModule(DD4T)

Tags: dd4t

I'm implementing DD4T, and publish binary files to broker DB.
To get binary from broker DB, I implemented "BinaryDistributionModule".

But following error occurred when request a WEB page.

```
   Exception type: NullReferenceException 
   Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013.TridionBinaryProvider.GetLastPublishedDateByUrl(String url)
    DD4T.Web.Binaries.BinaryFileManager.ProcessRequest(HttpRequest request)
    DD4T.Web.Binaries.BinaryDistributionModule.DistributionModule_OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object o, EventArgs eventArgs)
    System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I added following configuration to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     <add name="BinaryModule" type="DD4T.Web.Binaries.BinaryDistributionModule" />
</modules></system.webServer>
```

I'm using following applications(.NET and DD4T), and I think BinaryDistributionModule suppors those versions.

- .NET MVC4
- DD4T support for MVC4 1.31.1

Is any other configuration required?
Have anyone faced same problem?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add the binary file pattern regular expression to your web.config appSettings?

e.g.

```
<add key="DD4T.BinaryUrlPattern" value="^.*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)$" />
```

Comment: It works by adding the configuration to appSettings, but correct key value is "DD4T.BinaryUrlPattern".